# I'm trying to merge a small dataframe to another large one, looping through the small dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, merge

I am able to print the small dataframe and see it is being generated correctly, I've written it using the code below. My final result however contains just the result of the final merge, as opposed to passing over each one and merging them.

MIK_Quantiles is the first larger dataframe, df2_t is the smaller dataframe being generated in the while loop. The dataframes are both produced correctly and the merge works, but I'm left with just the result of the very last merge. I want it to merge the current df2_t with the already merged result (df_merged) of the previous loop. I hope this makes sense!

```
i = 0
while i < df_length - 1:   


    cur_bound = MIK_Quantiles['bound'].iloc[i]
    cur_percentile = MIK_Quantiles['percentile'].iloc[i]
    cur_bin_low = MIK_Quantiles['auppm'].iloc[i]
    cur_bin_high = MIK_Quantiles['auppm'].iloc[i+1]

    ### Grades/Counts within bin, along with min and max
    df2 = df_orig['auppm'].loc[(df_orig['bound'] == cur_bound) & (df_orig['auppm'] >= cur_bin_low) & (df_orig['auppm'] < cur_bin_high)].describe()

    ### Add fields of interest to the output of describe for later merging together
    df2['bound'] = cur_bound
    df2['percentile'] = cur_percentile
    df2['bin_name'] = 'bin name'
    df2['bin_lower'] = cur_bin_low
    df2['bin_upper'] = cur_bin_high
    df2['temp_merger'] =  str(int(df2['bound'])) + '_' + str(df2['percentile'])

    # Write results of describe to a CSV file and transpose columns to rows
    df2.to_csv('df2.csv')
    df2_t = pd.read_csv('df2.csv').T
    df2_t.columns = ['count', 'mean', 'std', 'min', '25%', '50%', '75%', 'max', 'bound', 'percentile', 'bin_name', 'bin_lower', 'bin_upper', 'temp_merger']

    # Merge the results of the describe on the selected data with the table of quantile values to produce a final output    
    df_merged = MIK_Quantiles.merge(df2_t, how = 'inner', on = ['temp_merger'])
    pd.merge(df_merged, df2_t)
    print(df_merged)


i = i + 1
```

Comment: If you want to merge, use merging methods, **do not iterate**. You should provide an example of data, there must be a vectorial solution to your problem

Comment: yeah, that is not the problem.. inside the loop, only `concat` is needed, and a single merge after the loop. @David is struggling with initializing the output before the loop

Comment: Merging in the loop was clearly wrong way to go about it - initialising a dataframe before the loop, into which all the smaller dataframes were concatenated before merging afterwards outside the loop (as suggested by Otto), solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop does not do anything meaningful, other than increment `i`.

You do a merge of 2 (static) dfs (`MIK_Quantiles` and `df2_t`), and you do that `df_length` number of times. Everytime you do that (first, i-th, and last iteration of the loop), you overwrite the output variable `df_merged`.

To keep in the output whatever has been created in the previous loop iteration, you need to concat all the created `df2_t`:

1. `df2 = pd.concat([df2, df2_t])` to 'append' the newly created data `df2_t` to an output dataframe `df2` during each iteration of the loop, so in the end all the data will be contained in `df2`

Then, **after** the loop, `merge` that one onto `MIK_Quantiles`

2. `pd.merge(MIK_Quantiles, df2)` (not `df2_t` (!)) to merge on the previous  output

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([]) # initialize your output
for i in range(0, df_length):
    df2_t = ...       # read your .csv files
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df2_t])
 df2 = ...      # do vector operations on df2 (process all of the df2_t at once)
 out = pd.merge(MIK_Quantiles, df2)
```

Comment: The problem is the same: everytime you do a merge, you re-create the same output variable. The loop does not "remember" what happened in the previous iteration. Are you maybe looking for `pd.concat([df_merged, df2_t])` to 'append' newly created to an existing dataframe? Or, do you want to merge on the previous output (`pd.merge(df_merged, df2_t)`)?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go. I just edited my reply

Comment: You need to initialize `df2` before the loop :) Now you are re-creating `df2` everytime the loop is executed.. Probably you want to look at a quick `loop` tutorial (the persistent variable needs to exist before the loop, and can be used after the loop, and can be changed within the loop. You cannot initialize the variable inside the loop, or overwrite the output)

Comment: thank you Otto, that has got it sorted